# Doubts about pandas axis working my code may be off

Tags: python, pandas, row, normalization

My issue is the following, I'm creating a pandas data frame from a dictionary that ends up looking like [70k, 300]. I'm trying to normalise each cell be it either by columns and after rows, and other way around rows then columns.

I ha asked a similar question before but this was with a [70k, 70k] data frame so square and it worked just by doing this

```
dfNegInfoClearRev = (df - df.mean(axis=1)) / df.std(axis=1).replace(0, 1)
dfNegInfoClearRev = (dfNegInfoClearRev - dfNegInfoClearRev.mean(axis=0)) / dfNegInfoClearRev.std(axis=0).replace(0, 1)
print(dfNegInfoClearRev)
```

This did what I needed for the case of a [70k, 70k]. A problem came up when I tried the same principle with a [70k, 300] if I do this:

```
dfRINegInfo = (dfRI - dfRI.mean(axis=0)) / dfRI.std(axis=0).replace(0, 1)
dfRINegInfoRows = (dfRINegInfo - dfRINegInfo.mean(axis=1)) / dfRINegInfo.std(axis=1).replace(0, 1)
```

I somehow end up with a [70k, 70k+300] full of NaNs with the same names.

I ended up doing this:

```
dfRIInter = dfRINegInfo.sub(dfRINegInfo.mean(axis=1), axis=0)
dfRINegInfoRows = dfRIInter.div(dfRIInter.std(axis=1), axis=0).fillna(1).replace(0, 1)

print(dfRINegInfoRows)
```

But I'm not sure if this is what I was trying to do and don't really understand why after the column normalisation which it does work [70k, 300] the row normalisation gives me a [70k, 70k+300], and I'm not sure if the way is working is what I'm trying to do. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your new code is doing what you want.

If we look at a 3x3 toy example:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([
    [1, 2, 3],
    [2, 4, 6],
    [3, 6, 9],
])
```

The `axis=1` mean is:

```py
df.mean(axis=1)

# 0    2.0
# 1    4.0
# 2    6.0
# dtype: float64
```

And the subtraction applies to each row (i.e., `[1,2,3] - [2,4,6]` element-wise, `[2-4-6] - [2,4,6]`, and `[3,6,9] - [2,4,6]`):

```py
df - df.mean(axis=1)

#      0    1    2
# 0 -1.0 -2.0 -3.0
# 1  0.0  0.0  0.0
# 2  1.0  2.0  3.0
```

So if we have `df2` shaped 3x2:

```py
df2 = pd.DataFrame([
    [1,2],
    [3,6],
    [5,10],
])
```

The `axis=1` mean is still length 3:

```py
df2.mean(axis=1)

# 0    1.5
# 1    4.5
# 2    7.5
# dtype: float64
```

And subtraction will result in the 3rd column being `nan` (i.e., `[1,2,nan] - [1.5,4.5,7.5]` element-wise, `[3,6,nan] - [1.5,4.5,7.5]`, and `[5,10,nan] - [1.5,4.5,7.5]`):

```py
df2 - df2.mean(axis=1)

#      0    1   2
# 0 -0.5 -2.5 NaN
# 1  1.5  1.5 NaN
# 2  3.5  5.5 NaN
```

If you make the subtraction itself along `axis=0` then it works as expected:

```py
df2.sub(df2.mean(axis=1), axis=0)

#      0    1
# 0 -0.5  0.5
# 1 -1.5  1.5
# 2 -2.5  2.5
```

So when you use a default subtraction between `(70000, 300)` and `(70000,1)`, there will be 69700 columns of `nan`.

Comment: Thank you! This clears my confusion a bit more. :)